# Is initializing a boolean to false or true more efficient?

Tags: java, performance

In java if you do not initiate a boolean it defaults to false.  So if i say

```
boolean myFavoriteBoolean = true;
```

Is this more work than

```
boolean myFavoriteBoolean = false;
```

My thinking is that in the first example it starts `false` and has to be set to `true` or is that not the case?  Also, I know this is a moot point from a performance perspective, but I'm asking because I'm interested if I understand how Java is working under the hood.

Comment: Describe _more work_. You think this will affect your program's performance?

Comment: I imagine the exact implementation would depend on a specific JVM

Comment: Performance doesn't play a role in this single specific line of code. Performance will be driven by your algorithm design and the usage of resources like cpu and RAM.

Comment: As in, is it two actions instead of one?  I think if it affects performance its tiny, but i'm interested in knowing if there is a difference between the two.

Comment: I really don't understand why though... i think its a legit question about the details of how Java does something.  Some comments as to why the down vote would be appreciated.

Comment: I quite like this question. I'd conject that even if Java has a default, it still has to initialise the memory in order to implement that default. So I'd expect the statements to have the same execution speed.

Comment: *I think if it affects performance its tiny, but i'm interested in knowing if there is a difference between the two.* this is like saying that your lungs will work more if you breathe wind for one more nano second than the last time you did. Does it make sense at all? The answer would be: it is JVM dependent, you can only make sure by looking at the generated bytecode and let the JVM optimize this ridiculous piece of code.

Comment: I would image that in the `true` case, the memory is initialized to zeros and then an extra microsecond is spent setting that one word of memory to one. But why would anyone care?

Comment: If you want to optimze your code this isn't worth thinking about. If tere is a difference, it probably wouldn't be measurable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are referring to an instance field of type `boolean`, then the answer is in [the JLS chapter regarding instance creation expressions.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.4)

> The new object contains new instances of all the fields declared in
>   the specified class type and all its superclasses. **As each new field
>   instance is created, it is initialized to its default value** (§4.12.5).
>
> [...]
>
> Next, the selected constructor of the specified class type is invoked. 
>   This results in invoking at least one constructor for each
>   superclass of the class type. This process can be directed by explicit
>   constructor invocation statements (§8.8) and is specified in detail in
>   §12.5.

After all [the super constructor calls](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5)

> **Execute the instance initializers and instance variable initializers
>   for this class, assigning the values of instance variable initializers
>   to the corresponding instance variables**, in the left-to-right order in
>   which they appear textually in the source code for the class. [...]

So

```
boolean val = false;
//and
boolean val = true;
```

behave the exact same way.

Answer (score 1):

If talking about fields, where there are default values: a created object is zeroed, so only setting it to true would need one more instruction - one would think.

However there is a idiotic case, demonstrating the difference between initialisation and default initialisation:

```
    class A {
        A() {
            b();
        }

        void b() {
        }
    }

    class B extends A {
        boolean c = false;
        boolean c2;

        @Override
        void b() {
            c = true;
            c2 = true;
        }

        B() {
            super();
            System.out.printf("%s %s%n", c, c2);
        }
    }

new B();
```

This will yield

```
false true
```

The reason: after the call to `super()` (or at the beginning of the constructor if no super), all field initialisations happen: at that point `c` was set to `true`, but is now iniitialized to `false`.

This is defined behaviour, and a reason **never** to call overridable functions in the constructor.

Mind also that in the first `B.b()` all fields of B still had their default value.

***So:***

- No initialisation is most efficient
- Any initialisation costs the same
- There is a difference between no initialisation and initialisation with default for idiotic code

I once removed an initialisation `= null` (cleaning up legacy code) causing an error.

Answer (score 1):

If the variable is an instance variable or a static variable, then the variable is default initialized to `false`, and there is a good chance that the JIT compiler can make use of this and optimize away an explicit initialization to `false`.  (In practice, heap memory is zeroed by the garbage collection / heap manager, and this happens irrespective of how the memory is going to be used.)

If the variable is a local variable, then there is no default initialization, and (typically) there is no automatic zeroing of stack frames that the JIT compiler can depend on.  Thus, you would expect initialization to `false` or `true` to take the same time.

---

However, this "smells" of premature optimization.  The actual difference is likely to be one or two native code instructions once the code is JIT compiled.  The chances are that it will make no significant difference to your application.  Furthermore, changing your program to exploit the (hypothetical) difference in performance will most likely make your code less readable, and have "knock on" consequences for the performance of other parts of your program.

Best practice is to only contemplate this kind of micro-optimization if:

- you have clear evidence that optimization is required; i.e. your application *does* run too slowly for representative benchmarks, and
- you have clear evidence that the code where the variable is declared and initialized is *actually* a performance bottlneck; i.e. the profiler tells you this.

Answer (score 1):

boolean fields default to false at the JVM level. Initializing to true results 3 extra bytecode instructions.

```
public class BoolTest {
  public boolean foo;
}
```

compiles to

```
0:  aload_0
1:  invokespecial   #1; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
4:  return
```

Compare to initializing to true

```
public class BoolTest {
  public boolean foo = true;
}
```

compiles to

```
0:  aload_0
1:  invokespecial   #1; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
4:  aload_0
5:  iconst_1
6:  putfield    #2; //Field foo:Z
9:  return
```

Comment: Warning: the bytecodes don't tell you how the code is going to perform.  The actual performance depends on the JIT compiler's ability to *optimize* the bytecodes ... including such things as leaving out unnecessary initialization instructions.